# Magento mails coming from[ftpUsername]@[servername.hostingcompany.com] on behalf of SENDER

Tags: email, magento

I have a Magento installation, and for certain recipients the transactional emails appear to be coming FROM something like **[ftpUsername]@[servername.hostingcompany.com] on behalf of SENDER** instead of just **FROM SENDER**. I hope that makes sense. How can I fix this ?

I know this has something to do with SMTP authentication or PHP mail but I cant find any such settings in magento and I don't know whether it's an issue with the magento settings, the server or the end users email clients. I also have a problem in that the mails send fine to all my own email accounts so I cant actually replicate myself it ( yet ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is because the [`on-behalf-of` header](https://www.google.com/search?q=on-behalf-of+header) is being set by Magento. I've never had this problem before, but it seems like it'd only make sense for Magento to do this if it were a "share with a friend" email. It should not be doing this for transactional emails.

If Magento isn't setting the header, then it might be set by the SMTP server you're using, in which case you'd need to contact your web host about that. If the sender is just `no-reply@yourdomain.tld`, then I don't see why it should use the `on-behalf-of` header. But apparently some web hosts attach this header automatically if you connect to the SMTP server on a standard port and only send the email properly if connected via [port 2525](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=033d21713f9364e9&hl=en).

Comment: Thanks. Can you happen to tell me whether Magento uses PHP mail or SMTP authentication, and if SMTP where the server details go ? All I could find was a spot saying 'Windows only' but my server is Linux.

Comment: @byronyasgur: By default, no. And most tutorials you'll find tell you to modify the core files (don't ever do this; there is almost always a better way, as is the case here), but you can use [this free Magento extension](http://www.aschroder.com/2009/08/magento-smtp-pro-extension-free-smtp-support/) to configure Magento to use SMTP authentication.

Comment: I think this answers my problem - will try it out next week, thanks.